# Specify a Fluent NHibernate automapping to add a unique constraint to all entities

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

My automapping:

```
 return Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(config)
                .Mappings(m =>
                          m.AutoMappings.Add(
                              AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Company>()
                                  .Where(
                                  t => t.Namespace == "DAL.DomainModel" && t.IsClass)
                                  .IgnoreBase<ReferenceEntity>()))
                .BuildSessionFactory();
```

So ReferenceEntity is an abstract class containing a string Name, and all my reference entities inherit from this class. I'd like to modify my automapping to add a unique constraint to the Name field for all entities that inherit from ReferenceEntity.

I've gathered it has something to do with .Setup but I'm a bit lost on how to proceed.

**note:** I'm using the Fluent NHibernate v1.0 RTM so conventions will be with the new style if that is relavent to my goal.

Answer (score 2):

If all your entities inherit from ReferenceEntity, wouldn't you want to create the unique constraint for the `Name` property on all the entities that are mapped?

But if you want to filter by entity base class, you can do it.  Use a convention to add the unique constraint to your mappings:

```
public class NameConvention : IPropertyConvention
{
    public void Apply(IPropertyInstance instance)
    {
        // Check the entity base class type
        if (instance.EntityType.BaseType.Name == "ReferenceEntity")
        {
            // Only add constraint to the .Name property
            if (instance.Name == "Name")
            {
                instance.Unique();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To get the convention (and all other conventions in the assembly) picked up by FNH, just add this line the `AutoMap` setup you have above:

```
.Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<NameConvention>()
```

---

Alex,

No the answer doesn't change. Here is an example, using the convention above.

```
public abstract class ReferenceEntity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class User : ReferenceEntity
{
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
}

public class Item : ReferenceEntity
{
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
}
```

This creates sql of:

```
create table Users (
    Id INTEGER not null,
   Email TEXT not null,
   Name TEXT not null unique,
   primary key (Id)
)

create table Items (
    Id INTEGER not null,
   Description TEXT,
   Name TEXT not null unique,
   primary key (Id)
)
```

As long as these are separate entities, it will create a unique constraint on the .Name property for each entity.

Comment: What I mean is that I have Company inheriting from ReferenceEntity and Port inheriting from ReferenceEntity. I want the unique constraint to apply seperately to these classes. I dont mind if there is a Company with the same name as a Port, so long as all ports have unique names and all companies have unique names. Does that change your answer at all?